# NGINX + HTTP/2 working partially

Tags: nginx

I just compiled a custom version of nginx for our new project.

NGINX -V:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.15
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --with-openssl=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2g --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --add-module=/usr/local/src/naxsi-master/naxsi_src/ --add-module=/root/custom-nginx/nginx-1.9.15/src/http/modules/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.11.33.0-beta
```

On the browsers from my work office http2 works fine. When I go home and test on my pc, http2 does not work in any browser. I cannot understand where the problem is.

I have the same windows 7, same browsers, everything the same.
Can somebody point me out the problem I am facing ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can think of two reasons why this might happen:

1. You are using anti virus software at home which performs MITM interception to enable it to scan traffic. See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/752767/trying-to-setup-http2-on-apache.
2. You are using a LoadBalancer or other such infrastructure that sits in front of your nginx server, when accessed externally.